# Selecting decimal(17,4) column from hive throws error in presto

Tags: hive, presto

Selecting (17, > 2) decimal columns from hive tables throws the following error in presto :

```
    ERROR -- : Command execution failed with exception: Query xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxx failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

io.prestosql.spi.type.ShortDecimalType
```

Currently on presto 317 release, not sure when we would be able to upgrade to a newer release, is there are workaround for this in this release ?

Comment: This is not a known problem, and it's not possible to advice a workaround without knowing all the detail.

Comment: I would suggest you file a new issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new with full stacktrace and steps you take to reproduce the problem. You can get the full stacktrace from web UI or running presto-cli with `--debug`.

Comment: Also, you may find Presto community helpful, particularly the #troubleshooting channel on [Presto slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).